# UK tuition fee Refund

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, uk-visa, study, refusal

I am planning on paying the tuition fees for my MSc at a UK university. I want to confirm if I will I get a refund if I get refused for a UK student visa.

Comment: Whether you're refunded will be up to the internal policies of the specific university. Ask the university's foreign students' office.

Comment: Not sure how you expect to get an answer when you haven’t even stated which university. Try googling its tuition refund policy. Some may retain an admin fee, most probably will refund in full unless eg refusal is a result of a fraudulent visa application, insufficient funds or supply of incorrect documents

Comment: I've answered this myself, so I'll leave it open. If the community decides that it should still be closed, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the rules around student visas insuring the disposition of any of the fees paid to Universities or other institutions of study. So no, the government places no requirement on the schools to guarantee a refund if a visa is not granted, nor do they in any way underwrite such fees. This is strictly according to the policy of the Unversity in question.